# Drupal views: How to aggregate CivCRM Relationships?

Tags: drupal-views, relationships

I was able to create Drupal Views that nicely lists Organization with their related individuals. It worked with both approaches with CiviCRM Relationships as well as CiviCRM Contacts as base view. Once you have this, it would seem simple then to switch on Aggregation and then count the contacts, but no. I tried what I could but with both approaches it returned illogically unexpected results.

Anyone successfully made a view to that can list Organizations with the number of their related Individuals? I would appreciate if you could share your experience.

Answer (score 1):

In the past when I have tried doing this sort of thing I have had to use a Drupal module.

Maybe try this module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator